# Selection based on JOINED table performance issues

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table with institutions. This entity has many users. A users has an string field that can be empty. If this is empty the user is not active. Now, I want to query all active institutions, this is defined by an active user in the institution; so if the institutions has only 1 active user, it is active. If it has no active users, it is not active.

The user table is *huge* (1.5 million records). When I do a join with the users table with constraint active_field <> '' it takes too long.

What would be the best approach to optimize this query?

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.  I can't figure out what the data structure is from the description.

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want:

```
select distinct institution_id
from users u
where stringfield <> '' and stringfield is not null;
```